# Trying to integrate Newrelic mobile SDK in monitor app for performance but getting below error while gradle build

Tags: android, gradle, newrelic, newrelic-platform

Gradle version: 8.0.1

com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:6.10.0

com.newrelic.agent.android:agent-gradle-plugin:7.0.0

Steps to Reproduceintegrate the agent as suggested in docs and try to build the project.

Relevant Logs / Console output```* Exception is:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/build/api/variant/AndroidComponentsExtension

    at java.desktop/com.sun.beans.introspect.MethodInfo.get(MethodInfo.java:70)

    at java.desktop/com.sun.beans.introspect.ClassInfo.getMethods(ClassInfo.java:80)

    at com.newrelic.agent.android.NewRelicGradlePlugin.apply(NewRelicGradlePlugin.groovy:43)

    at com.newrelic.agent.android.NewRelicGradlePlugin.apply(NewRelicGradlePlugin.groovy)

    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ImperativeOnlyPluginTarget.applyImperative(ImperativeOnlyPluginTarget.java:43)

    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.RuleBasedPluginTarget.applyImperative(RuleBasedPluginTarget.java:51)

    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.addPlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:187)

    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.access$100(DefaultPluginManager.java:52)

    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager$AddPluginBuildOperation.run(DefaultPluginManager.java:282)

    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)

    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)

    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)

    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)

    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)

    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)

    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)

    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)

    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.lambda$doApply$0(DefaultPluginManager.java:167)
```

```
2023-08-16 13:28:15.742 16966-16966 newrelic                com.abc        I  isInstrumented: checking for Mono instrumentation flag - NO
2023-08-16 13:28:15.742 16966-16966 newrelic                com.abc           E  Failed to detect New Relic instrumentation. The current runtime variant may be excluded from instrumentation, or instrumentation failed during your build process.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a follow-up question before going deeper to answering, did you apply New Relic plugin on app level gradle file?